# Installing CyanogenMod 11 on Karbonn A52+

Tags: cyanogenmod, karbonn

I need a little help in installing CyanogenMod 11 in my rooted Karbonn A52+, though it's running the stock recovery & I haven't been able to install CWM as it isn't compatible with my device.. So could you please guide me in installing CyanogenMod 11 on my device?

Device details:

- Android Version: 4.2.2 Jelly Bean
- Root Access: Yes
- CPU: 1.2 GHz Dual Core Mediatek
- RAM: 512 MB

Comment: Try search and research until you get a Cyanogenmod build and a custom recovery for your device. That's something you should do to help yourself. We can help you out in flashing it.

Comment: See [Does cyanogenmod work on my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/125825)

Answer (score 0):

your device is not officially supported, and I did not find an unofficial build. also there is no custom recovery available. if you **really** want to use cyanogenmod, buy another phone.