# Does cyanogenmod work on my device?

Tags: cyanogenmod, root-access

I use a rooted "AOC tb07mc" does cyanogenmod work on my tablet? 
And if it does, how to mod it?

Comment: "AOC tb07mc" does not come up at all through a Google search (other than this post). Firelord is right- you should check directly through CM or check [xda forums](http://www.xda-developers.com/).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, I searched for my tablet and I didn't find it, it's OK I don't want to mod anymore . Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

#### This is a device independent answer.

For new comers: Whenever you want to find a CyanogenMod (CM) build for your device, find out whether your device is supported officially by CM or not. You can do that easily. Click [here](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/) and search for your device's name.

Officially supported devices usually have a separate page for information including flashing instructions, device specifications, name of  maintainer(s) among other things. Click [here](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Devices#vendor=;) to know more.

In the event your device's name doesn't show up (i.e. not officially supported), then head to [Unofficial Ports](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Unofficial_Ports) page. The entries in the list are -- ideally supposed to be -- added by the respective developer(s) or maintainer(s) of that unofficial build.

If you still don't see your device's name anywhere, then either, the developer didn't add the entry to that last list or nobody has yet ported CM to your device.

For the case when you do not see your device's name anywhere in both official and unofficial devices list, then search the ROM on the web, specifically [XDA forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/) but not limited to that. You'll have to try multiple queries for better results from search engine and possibly, even the [Advanced Search](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/35890) if Google is your choice of search engine.

As for flashing the CM ROM -- provided that you do have a build in your hand -- you would probably be able to see the instructions from wherever you got to know about ROM's download link. If not, use web search or our [site's search](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/searching). If nothing shows up, [ask us](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).